# git post-receive hook permissions

Tags: git, permissions, centos, githooks

I did setup a multi-user gitolite environment, but I don't get the post-receive hook working.

The problem is that I have to deal with two users on my VPS server.

For example, if `example.com` is my main domainname for my VPS server and I want to deploy to `dev.example.com`, then my user `git` needs write access to the public_html/dev folder of user `example`.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 275 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: Could not switch to '/home/example/public_html': Permission denied
To ssh://git@example.com:22/project.git
   e0a35f7..4f747e6  master -> master
```

In other word how do I setup a post-receive hook from:

`home/git/repositories/project.git/hooks`

to a hosted folder owned by example:example:

`home/example/public_html/dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved.

I was changing group permissions for hours and it behaved very strange.
Later on I realized that you need to log out en log in the user to get the new permissions working.

Doh!! :p